# Why cant' I find iPhone SE simulator in Xcode 7.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7, iphone-se

[image]

As shown from the above screenshot,there is no `iPhone SE` option in the simulator list in the latest Xcode version 7.3.

Comment: The iPhone SE has only just been released; after Xcode 7.3.  Also what would the iPhone SE simulator give you that the iPhone 5S Simulator would not?

Comment: @trojanfoe for the same reason that there's a 5 & 5s, a 6 and 6s. I presume there are different APIs available. I'm not an expert in underlying simulator architecture but if there's a new device out, seems like I should test against it. I expected that Apple would make it available for download through Xcode 7.3 or bundle it with an updated version of Xcode.

Comment: To add to @skotturi, I have a user in an app experiencing a bug that is only happening in his SE. Is it not conceivable that a different device could have different behavior? heh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beta version of Xcode 8 has iPhone SE simulators:

[image]

Why they didn't come out when the phone was released, I'm not sure. Maybe a spring release of a new iPhone doesn't correspond with Xcode release cycles.